# Regular Expression with wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace some content using regular expression and not able to do it, can you please have a look..

My Input: `<Tag>E2iamjunkblabla</Tag>`
Expected Output: `<Tag>E2done</Tag>`

I am trying this:

```
string input = "<Tag>E2iamjunkblabla</Tag>";
string output= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "<Tag>E2*</Tag>", "<Tag>E2done</Tag>");
```

What am I doing wrong? Also is there any way to retain first 3 characters(numbers or alphbets) after E2?
I mean the output should be

```
<Tag>E2iam</Tag>
```

Comment: `*` matches the preceeding item multiple times (it will match the 2), it's not a wildcard. You probably want `.*` instead

Comment: You need to learn regex.  `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the last character.

Comment: Can you post the exact expected input/output? When you say keep the first three - I am assuming those 3 characters could be anything....

Comment: @Charleh the input is the same..
     <Tag>E2iamjunkblabla</Tag>

Comment: @SLaks Yes I have to learn it first... Seems to be complex in the begining but i will learn it soon.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
string input = "<Tag>E2iamjunkblabla</Tag>";

string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "<Tag>E2(...).*</Tag>", @"<Tag>E2$1done</Tag>");
```

To break it down:

The match:

Match `<Tag>` then match `E2` then match any character 3 times `(...)` (the parenthesis mean to store that capture in a group), then match any character zero or more times `.*` followed by the literal `</Tag>`

The replace:

Replace the value with `<Tag>E2` then the value of capture group 1 `$1` then the literal `done</Tag>`

Let me know if you have issues - and read up on regex! (oh and there are probably a load of ways to do this, this is just one of them)

Comment: "the parenthesis mean to store that capture in a group" - awesome